# How to use Image.getcolors() on an image with more than 256 colours?

Tags: python-imaging-library

From PIL docs:

> PARAMETERS: maxcolors – Maximum number of colors. If this number is
> exceeded, this method returns None. The default limit is 256 colors.

Not sure I understand the above. Can I set maxcolors to any number?
Does convert("P") reduce the number of colours to <= 256?

```
from PIL import Image

path2pics = '/home/pedro/Pictures/' # len(pics) = 40
pics = glob.glob(path2pics + '*.jpg')
for pic in pics:
    im = Image.open(pic).convert("P") 
    im1 = Image.Image.getcolors(im) # gives a list of tuples as output
    print(f'length of colour count list is {len(im1)}.')
```

The above code gave an output for every image in pics.

This image is very big and returned nothing using convert("RGB"), not sure why:

```
img3 = '/home/pedro/Downloads/damage_back_left_edge.jpg'
im = Image.open(img3).convert("RGB") # no output using convert("RGB") or convert("CMYK")
im1 = Image.Image.getcolors(im)
im1 # no output maybe too many colours
im1 == None # True
```

If I use convert('P') or convert('L') it works:

```
im = Image.open(img3).convert("P")
im1 = Image.Image.getcolors(im)
len(im1) # = 111

im = Image.open(img3).convert("L")
im1 = Image.Image.getcolors(im)
len(im1) # = 256
```

How should I deal with an image that has more than 256 colours?
What does convert() do? Reduce the number of colours to 256 or less?

I thought I could just set maxcolors=2048 for example, but that did not work.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. `getcolors()` tells you all the colours in an image and how often each one occurs - it doesn't change the number of colours in the image and it has a limit (which you can change) so that it doesn't have to allocate an array with 16 million entries in order to count every possible colour's frequency. `convert('P')` converts an image to a palette image with under 256 unique colours. HTH.